# unable to install intel HAXM for windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, intel, haxm

i want o install Intel HAXM. unable to install it. following error pop ups as shown in screen shot. 
I have turned on VT from bios.
VT is turned on, is showing.
Still i get this error. kindly check and reply.

[image]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software installation tech support.

Comment: i know, but i am getting problem to run VM in android studio, thus i posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters is the CPU - must be Intel processor that supports VT and NX bit (XD) - you can check your CPU # at http://ark.intel.com 
Also make sure hyperV off bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
XD bit is on bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Use the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable "Hardware-assisted virtualization" in Avast Premium to install support for HAXM/VT-x in Android Studio.